# AS3, Flash - Error

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

After that i made my AS3 send variables to my PHP i am getting the following errors:

```
Error: Error #2101: The String passed to URLVariables.decode() must be a URL-encoded query     string containing name/value pairs.
    at Error$/throwError()
    at flash.net::URLVariables/decode()
    at flash.net::URLVariables()
    at flash.net::URLLoader/onComplete()
Cannot display source code at this location.
```

Any idea on what to do against this?
This happens only if I run it directly from the flash file?

Is this because I am using localhost on my machine to do this?

Comment: any chances to see the the code you are using to send this request?

Comment: Sure. Didn't think about that.. Here: http://pastebin.com/uh0prTT1

Answer (score 0):

This usually means that the information passed back from PHP (to your onComplete handler function) is not formatted in name/value pairs.

e.g. name=Mark

If you intend to have PHP pass name/value pairs back you should set your URLLoader to:

```
yourLoaderName.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;
```

or if the response is not name/value pairs:

```
yourLoaderName.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.TEXT;
```